# calculate the molecular weight of each molecule in the formulas.txt file

Tags: c++

why does my program not correctly calculate the molecular weight of my formulas file? i know that it has to do with the double get_total_weight(table& hash_table, string line_input, int i) and the double total_weight. but i don't know what I'm doing wrong. i know if i change the total_weight to something like 5, the that is what the weight is for all of them.

Here is the formulas.txt file:

```
H2SO4
Al2(SO4)3
H2O
CH4
C6H12O6
(CH3)3  
C3H7
AuI3
Bi2O3
Ga(C2H3O2)3
Cu3(PO4)2
In(OH)3
Li(AlSi2O6)
Sb2OS2
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <cctype>      // Provides toupper
#include <cstdlib>     // Provides EXIT_SUCCESS and size_t
#include <iostream>    // Provides cin, cout
#include "table.h"    // Provides the table class
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>    // Provides strchr
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

void read_in_table(table& hash_table, string line_input);
double get_total_weight(table& hash_table, string line_input, int i);

int main()
{
    string line_input;
    table hash_table;
    char dataFileName[] = "PeriodicTableElements.txt";

    // I've got the file name, now try to open the file for reading
    ifstream fileData;
    fileData.open(dataFileName, 0);
    if (fileData.good() == false)
    {
        cout << "ERROR: can't open data file: " << dataFileName << endl;

        // wait for the user to press enter to quit
        cout << endl << "Press the [Enter] key to quit...";
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }

    char dataFileName1[] = "formulas.txt";

    // I've got the file name, now try to open the file for reading
    ifstream fileData1;
    fileData1.open(dataFileName1, 0);
    if (fileData1.good() == false)
    {
        cout << "ERROR: can't open data file: " << dataFileName1 << endl;

        // wait for the user to press enter to quit
        cout << endl << "Press the [Enter] key to quit...";
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }


    // I've got the data file open.
    // read and use the data
    string hash;
    while (getline(fileData, hash))
    {
        cout << hash << endl;   
        cout << endl;
    }
    while (getline(fileData1, hash))
    {
        cout << hash << endl;
        getline(fileData, line_input, '\n');
        double total_weight = get_total_weight(hash_table, line_input, 0);
        cout << line_input << "=" << total_weight << endl;

    }

    fileData.close();
    cout << endl << "Press the [Enter] key to quit...";
    getchar();
}

void read_in_table(table& hash_table, string line_input)
{
    double weight;
    int i = 0;
    while (line_input[i] != ' ')
        ++i;
    string element = line_input.substr(0, i);
    int element_number = element[0] - 0;
    int weight_length = line_input.size() - i;
    string weight_string = line_input.substr(i, weight_length);
    istringstream convert(weight_string);
    if (!(convert >> weight))
        weight = 0;
}
double get_total_weight(table& hash_table, string line_input, int i)
{
    int j;
    int multiplier;
    double total_weight = 0.0;
    double weight;
    while (line_input[i] != '\0')
    {
        j = i;
        if (line_input[i] == '(')
        {
            ++i;
            int k = i;
            while (line_input[k + 1] != ')')
                k++;
            string line_help = line_input.substr(i, k - i + 1);
            weight = get_total_weight(hash_table, line_help, 0);
            i = k + 2;
            if (line_input[i] == '\0')
                total_weight = total_weight + weight * 1;
        }
        else
        {
            while (islower(line_input[i + 1]))
                i++;
            int k = i - j + 1;
            string element = line_input.substr(j, k);
            double element_number = element[0] - 0;
            weight = hash_table.retrieve(element_number, element);
            ++i;
            if (!(isdigit(line_input[i])))
                total_weight = total_weight + weight * 1;
        }
        j = i;
        while (isdigit(line_input[i]))
            i++;
        int k = i - j;
        string line_input_passer = line_input.substr(j, k);
        istringstream convert(line_input_passer);
        if (!(convert >> multiplier)) //give the value to weight using the characters in the stream
            multiplier = 0;
        total_weight = total_weight + weight * multiplier;
    }
    return total_weight;
}
```

Comment: Make sure your file path is correct.  Make sure the file exists.  Make sure you have permissions to read the file.

Comment: As @JustinRandall suggests, your path is likely incorrect. Try creating an output file and see where that file is created. That is where it the library is trying to find the files that you want it to read.

Comment: Most likely the process is not running in the same directory where the files are located.  Give the full paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

always provide full path to your file location. Change below two statement and that will fix your issue.

```
string pathway = "PeridicTableElements.txt";//change this code like below

string pathway = "/path/to/this/file/location/PeridicTableElements.txt";//In Unix/Linux

string pathway = "C:\\path\\to\\file\\location\\PeridicTableElements.txt";//In Windows
```

And

```
 string pathway1 = "formulas.txt";// change this code like below

 string pathway1 = "/path/to/this/file/location/formulas.txt";//In Unix/Linux

 string pathway1 = "C:\\path\\to\\file\\location\\formulas.txt";// In Windows
```

Comment: @jonathon was it related to a path issue or something else. If it was something else please provide an answer your to own question.

Answer (score 0):

i was able to get it to work but i had to change string pathway and string pathway1 to

```
char dataFileName[] = "PeriodicTableElements.txt"; `then put` ifstream fileData; fileData.open(dataFileName, 0); if(fileData.good() == false)
{
cout << "ERROR: cant open data file:" << dataFileName << endl;
cout << endl << "Press[enter] to quit...";
getchar();
return -1;
}
```